# Spring Cloud Config Server with git backend using github access token

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I can't get access to my github repo

I have private github repo with two-factor auth as a config storage for my Spring Cloud Config server.

I want to use github access token for authorization

My application.yml contains:

```
cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
        uri: https://oauth2:<my_token_here>@github.com/<my_repo_here>.git
```

I got an error

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://oauth2@github.com/<my_repo_here>.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the

spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=your_github_username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=your_github_password

and things should workout for you

Comment: add into bootstrap file